# Exclude directories from wget to create sitemap

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, terminal

Im trying to use a shell script to scrape a website to get a list of all pages. I found the shell script "Written by Elmar Hanlhofer https://www.plop.at" and it works well. However, I need to exclude directories and the documentation isn't working for me.

```
# Example, exclude files from /print and /slide: 
# files=$(find | grep -i html | grep -v "$SITE/print" | grep -v "$SITE/slide")
```

I need to exclude a forum install located at /support (and all children directories) so I modify the code to be:

```
files=$(find | grep -i html | grep -v "$SITE/support")
```

However it is still scanning /support/directory/directory/ etc. How do I modify the grep command to exclude /support AND ALL CHILD DIRECTORIES?

I am very new to linux / unix commands, so I may not be expressing this correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the link to the script. `find | grep -i html | grep -v "$SITE/support"` has nothing to do with wget. You need pass something like  `--exclude-directories=support`  to wget commands.

Comment: Here is the link to the script -> https://www.plop.at/en/xml-sitemap.html I followed the inline documentation around line 117.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original script will download whole site, run find to filter out content you don't want.

The section related to wget is copied below,

```sh
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --no-parent \
     --directory-prefix="$TMP" \
     --domains $DOMAIN \
     --user-agent="$AGENT" \
     $URL >& $WGET_LOG
```

To exclude `support` directory, add `--exclude-directories` option,

```sh
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --no-parent \
     --directory-prefix="$TMP" \
     --domains $DOMAIN \
     --user-agent="$AGENT" \
     --exclude-directories=/support \ 
     $URL >& $WGET_LOG
```

Read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/744334/363579) if you want to have more control on directories.

Comment: Thank you. Was struggling with syntax with similar solution. --exclude-directories=/support,  /foo, /bar \ is that correct?

Comment: Yes, multiple exclusions are separated by commas. `www.example.com/a/b`, if you want to exclude directory b, `--exclude-directories=/a/b`, not `--exclude-directories=/b`.

Comment: To do it recursively (even though I see --recursive \ in the wget command, would I change this files=$(find | grep -i html) to this files=$(find | grep -r html)? I want to exclude all child directories of the one's listed IE /a/b without having to list all children of subdirectories.

Comment: No you don't need to change `files=$()` command. If you want directory `/a/b` to show up, but not its children, I think it should be changed to  `--exclude-directories=/a/b/*`.